# Incompatible foreign key when attempting to link tables in Django?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am trying to make a couple basic models, and link them together with a foreign key.

**First tool**

```
class tool1(models.Model):
    tool_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        primary_key=True,
        verbose_name="Tool",
    )

    description = models.CharField(
        default="",
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name="Description",
        help_text="Describe tool here",
    )
```

I migrated this to the DB first. That worked fine, Django successfully created the new table in the database. Then I tried to make the reference via foreign key.

**Referencing tool**

```
class Tool2(models.Model):
     tool1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Tool,
        default=None,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
        blank=True
    )
```

For some reason the other tools I reference work, but this one will not. I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'tool1' and referenced column 'tool_id' in foreign key constraint [FK Name] are incompatible.")
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening because the referencing tool is successfully referencing multiple other tools, but it will not link to this one. What is the reason for this error? And how can I fix it so that I can link the tables? Why are they incompatible?

Comment: Was the `ForeignKey` already there *before* you created a new `primary_key=True`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think so. I made the tool1 model, then migrated. Then after that I tried adding the foreign key and got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing primary key constraint from tool_id. `models.Model` have primary key field which you inherit.

Edit:
Don't use verbose name when setting foreign key. When setting foreign key in tool2, use tool1 instead of tool. tool is verbose name for tool1 and verbose name is only for humans, so it's not relevant for database.

Comment: I tried both and neither seemed to work, I don't understand why removing the primary key would help though.

Comment: It's not removing, you have primary key field which is inherited from Model class

Answer (score 0):

Check if the type of foreign key that you've created is the same data type of reference table **id**

If they are not the same, you have to fix it by changing one of the column types to match the other will allow you to create the table with the foreign key constraint.